# my recyclerview not showing data it is only loading progressbar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I am developing a new app and I have implemented `recyclerview` but it is not loading data only showing progress bar loading I did not understand where is the problem.

I am developing a new app and I have implemented `recyclerview` but it is not loading data only showing progress bar loading I did not understand where is problem

below my MemberActivity.kt class where I have implemented network call

```
    class MemberActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private var memberAdapter:MemberAdapter? = null
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_member)
    
            val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
            compositeDisposable.add(
                ServiceBuilder.buildService(SpectrumInterface::class.java).getMembers()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(
                        { members -> onResponse(members) },
                        { t -> onFailure(t) })
            )
    
        }
    
        private fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    
        private fun onResponse(members: List<Member>) {
    
            memberAdapter = MemberAdapter()
    
    
            recyclerView.apply {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MemberActivity)
                adapter = memberAdapter
            }
        }
    }
```

```
below my Adapter class
```

```
        class MemberAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder>() {
    
        private val members = mutableListOf<Member>()
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int
        ): MemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder {
          val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.member_list, parent, false)
            return MemberViewHolder(view)
    
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
           return members.size
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder, position: Int) {
         return holder.bind(members[position])
        }
    
        class MemberViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    
            private val memberAge: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberAge)
            private val memberName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberName)
            private val lastName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastName)
            private val firstName:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstName)
            private val emailAddress:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress)
            private val phone:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone)
    
            fun bind(member: Member) {
    
                memberAge.text = member.age.toString()
                memberName.text = member.name.toString()
                lastName.text = member.name.last
                firstName.text = member.name.first
                emailAddress.text = member.email
                phone.text = member.phone
    
            }
        }
    
    }
```

below my ServiceBuilder.kt

```
    object ServiceBuilder {
        private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build()
    
    
        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.npoint.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .client(client)
            .build()
    
        fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
            return retrofit.create(service)
        }
    }
```

below
SpectrumInterface.kt

```
    interface SpectrumInterface {
        
    
        @GET("15c43d65bc7a989f47f1")
        fun getMembers(): Observable<List<Member>>
    
    }
```

below Member.kt

```
    data class Member(
        @SerializedName("age")
        val age: Int,
        @SerializedName("email")
        val email: String,
        @SerializedName("_id")
        val id: String,
        @SerializedName("name")
        val name: Name,
        @SerializedName("phone")
        val phone: String
    )
```

Comment: after setting data to adpater do notifyDataSetChanged() also I don't see you passing data to the adpater memberAdapter = MemberAdapter() there is a mutablelist of memebers but is not initialized

Comment: do you think thats the issue

Comment: @PedroAGSantos how can I initialized mutable list of members so that it can show data can you explain with coding sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your adpater since you are create a new one every time you receive data do the following

```
class MemberAdapter(private val members: List<Member>())
```

to initialize do

```
MemberAdapter(memebers)
```

then after this code

```
    recyclerView.apply {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MemberActivity)
                adapter = memberAdapter
            }

memberAdapter.notififyDataSetChanged()
```

**Proper Solution**

Make only one MemberAdpater

so transform this into Immutable
in the activity

```
private val memberAdapter:MemberAdapter = MemberAdapter()
```

then in adapter make a function that replaces the data

something like

```
private val members: mutableListOf<Member>()

fun setMembers(data: List<Member>) {
    members.clear()
    members.addAll(data)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error class MemberAdapter(private val members: mutableListOf<Member>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder>() {
 here

Comment: class MemberAdapter(private val members: mutableListOf<Member>)  I am getting error here

Comment: cus it hast to be List since mutableListOf just creates a list so it's not setting a type I thing you should take look into basic kotlin first also study the Adapter Pattern in Android

Comment: I just my answer please take a look

Comment: bro I know kotlin but you answer incorrect class MemberAdapter(private val members: List<Member>()) and below private val members: mutableListOf<Member>()

fun setMembers(data: List<Member>) {
    members.clear()
    members.add(data)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
} how this possible

Comment: class MemberAdapter( private val members: List<Member>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder>() {
    
    fun setMembers(data: List <Member>) {
        members.clear()
        members.add(data)
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } here is error occurring you can add list in setmember function bro

Comment: in the activity you have an object memberAdapter right ? so you can do memberAdapter. setMembers(members)

Comment: I just answer your question but then I give proper solution Proper Solution so below proper solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219861/discussion-between-edgar-davids-and-pedroagsantos).

Comment: private val members: mutableListOf<Member>()

fun setMembers(data: List<Member>) {
    members.clear()
    members.add(data)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
} I cant add members.add()

Comment: did you manage ? I just edited my answer cus you need to use addAll() to add a list into a list